# How to override fields of a modelform in a modelformset?

Tags: django

I have a special case where the users should be able to change the status of the deal, but not the `deal_type`. Therefore I thought I change the widget of the dropdown into a text field.

Hence I would like to override deal_type's widget in my formset and I subclassed `BaseModelFormSet` and passed that in as a parameter to the factory:

```
deal_formset = modelformset_factory(Deal, formset=BaseDealFormSet, fields = {'status', 'deal_type'}, extra=0)


class Deal(models.Model):
    deal_id             = UUIDField()
    status              = models.ForeignKey(DealStatus)    
    deal_type           = models.ForeignKey(DealType)    


class BaseDealFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):    
    deal_type        = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(  attrs={'readonly': 'True'}))    

    def clean_deal_type(self):
        return self.instance.deal_type
```

However in the template `{{fs.deal_type}}` the widget is still shown as a dropdown and not a textfield.

I am not even sure, if this would exactly work as I intended , that is seeing the selected value of the dropdown as a textfield. But at least I should see a change of the widget, right? But it seems it is completely ignored.

What am I missing? Thanks,

Comment: ahh right. How would I override the actual form in this case? Because the `modelformset_factory` is creating the form of the Model directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a ModelForm subclass with your customizations, and pass that as the `form` argument to `modelformset_factory`.

```
class DealForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    deal_type = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'True'}))

    def clean_deal_type(self):
        return self.instance.deal_type

...

deal_formset = modelformset_factory(Deal, form=DealForm,
                                    fields=['status', 'deal_type'], extra=0)
```

Note there's a fair amount of flexibility in how you do this - the `fields` could go in an inner Meta class on the form, you could keep your modelformset subclass and put the form declaration there, and so on.